# Spring API exception causes filter to be executed

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-filter

I have a spring boot application, i am using SecurityConfig. I am using `web.ignoring().antMatchers` to allow certain (**/allowed_api**) apis to be accessed without going through the **authFilter**. If **/allowed_api** does not throw an exception, everything works as expected. I can access **/allowed_api**  without **authFilter** being invoked.

#### Problem

The problem is if **/allowed_api** throws an exception (any exception 404, 500, etc) , then for some reason, **authFilter**  is invoked, and the api throws an authentication failure exception.

How can i make sure **authFilter**  is never invoked for a certain api (**/allowed_api**)?

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity 
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/allowed_api");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.addFilterAfter(new AuthFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);

    }
}
```

Comment: You'd better post the details of the 'authentication failure exception' thrown by the API.

Comment: @f.nasim thanks, for the response, the issue is the authentication failure exception. The issue is, when  "/allowed_api" throws an exception, the AuthFilter is invoked. When  "/allowed_api" **DOES NOT** throws an exception, AuthFilter is not invoked.

Comment: why do you even have a custom filter for?

Comment: @Toerktumlare i use the filter for third party authentication

Answer (score 0):

By default, Spring Boot delegates error handling to the `/error` context path: whenever an endpoint throws an error (e.g. `/allowed_api` in your case), the `/error` endpoint takes over. As you have relaxed security check for `/allowed_api` but not for `/error`, authentication filter kicks in on any error at `/allowed_api`.

Relaxing security check for `/error`, just as you did for `/allowed_api`, should do.

Comment: this was the issue, thanks